# Prove that $\int_If\phi dm=\int_Ig\phi dm$ implies $f=g$ a.e over $I$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, alternative-proof, measurable-functions

Let $f,g\in L^2(I)$. Prove that if $$\int_If\phi dm=\int_Ig\phi dm$$ for all $\phi\in C(I)$, then $f=g$ a.e over $I$, which is a finite interval.

**Attempt**

By hypothesis $\int_If\phi dm=\int_Ig\phi dm$.

Then considering this result 
 [$\int_Efdm=\int_Egdm\implies f=g, a.e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712442/proof-of-int-ef-dm-int-eg-dm-implies-f-g-equal-almost-everywhere)

implies  $f\phi=g\phi$ a.e

From here, how could I 'remove' $\phi$ to have only $f=g$?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt has errors. You cannot conclude that $f \phi =g\phi$ a.e. because the given equation holds only for the given interval. It is not given that the integrals over any measurable set $E$ are equal. This makes the result more involved.

As commented above, you have to assume that $I$ is a finite interval.

Here are some hints: given any closed interval $[a,b]$ contained in $I$ we can find continuous functions $\phi_n$ such that $ 0 \leq \phi_n \leq  1$ and $\phi_n(x) \to 1$ if $ x\in [a,b]$ and $\phi_n(x) \to 0$ if $ x\notin [a,b]$. Applying the hypothesis and letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx=\int_a^{b} g(x)dx$  (1) for all such intervals $[a,b]$. We are still far away from the conclusion because we cannot immediately replace the interval $[a,b]$ by an arbitrary Borel set. One result that gives $f=g$ a.e. immediately is Lebesgue's Theorem. If you divide both sides of (1) by $b-a$ and let $b \to a$ you get $f=g$ almost everywhere from this theorem.

Alternative proof: the proof is much simpler if you know that $L^{2}$ can approximated by continuous functions. Let $\phi_n$ be continuous functions converging in $L^{2}$ to $f-g$. Then you can pass to the limit in $\int_I(f-g)\phi_n=0$ to get $\int (f-g)^{2}=0$ which implies $f=g$ a.e..

Comment: How is that you can switch a continuous function $\phi$ by a sequence $\phi_n$ ?

Comment: The hypothesis is for all $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Regarding the first proof, why one can have $\phi_n(x)\to1$ if $x\in[a,b]$ and $\phi_n(x)\to0$ if $x\not\in[a,b]$?

Comment: Just make $\phi_n$ piece-wise linear with the value $1$ on $[a,b]$ and $0$ on the complement of $(a-\frac 1 n, b+\frac 1 n)$.  @Magic_Isa

Comment: oh ok. And when you say: Applying the hypothesis and letting $n\to\infty$ we get $\int_a^{b} f(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_a^{b} g(x)\phi(x)dx$, how was $n\to\infty$ is applied? afaiu, if $n\to\infty$, then $\phi_n(x)\to1$ but then how is related to the integrals equality?

Comment: @Magic_Isa I was not supposed to have $\phi$ in (1). Corrected the answer.

Comment: I am gonna start a bounty, to understand all thoroughly